# How do you translate future perfect into Latin? For instance, how do you say "The test starts at 9 AM and it will not have ended by 11 AM." in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

My attempt would be "*Examen incipit in nona hora ante meridiem et non finiet ante undecimam horam ante meridiem.*", but I am almost sure that's incorrect.

Comment: I think they could be downvoting you b/c [future perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_tenses#Future_perfect_indicative) is a standard tense in Latin, so you could be asking a grammar question one could easily find in reference books. In this case it would be [**finiverit**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/finiverit#Latin).

Comment: Re: the reminder of the translation, _non finiverit [priusquam](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=prior&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) hora undecima_ sounds better to me, but I'm not sure about what would be the most idiomatic choice.

Comment: @Rafael Priusquam goes with ablative?

Comment: Quam is an adverb, not a preposition. Hence _priusquam_ goes with whatever case is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic way to say this using the future perfect is as follows:

*Examen incipit hora nona mane et non desierit (or desiverit) ante undecimam horam.*

Word by word:

```
"Examen" = test/examination
"incipit" = starts/begins
"hora nona mane" = at the ninth hour of the morning
    NB: Roman time started at sunrise, but for simplification 
    in this modern context, we're using it as 9am.
"et" = and
"non desierit" = will not have ended (future perfect)
"ante" = until/before
"undecimam horam" = the eleventh hour (again, taken in a modern context as 11am)
```

Your rendering is correct except the verb choice could be better. *finio* is used when we put a limit on something and usually it takes an object. When we want to say something comes to end, it is more usual to use the word *desino*. Your word is still fine, but *desino* might be a better choice.

Example: from Virgil Georgics: *desinit ante decem* ("ends before the tenth [year]")

Comment: Is it *undecima*?

Comment: @Cerberus I fixed that.